# Issue while creating account

Tags: stellar-core, horizon

I have set up a private network with core & horizon, when creating accounts I am getting internal server error.

In horizon logs I am getting msg="select failed: pq: relation "signers" does not exist"

I did horizon db init and it was successful and follwing tables were created:

[image]

Also history_elder_ledger is not increasing. 
Have I missed something? Following data is in gorp_migrations table post db init.

[image]

Comment: What does your stellar-core tables look like? signers is stellar-core, not horizon.

Comment: In the future, please copy output as text. This improves search-ability and helps people to answer your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error at Horizon = `msg="select failed: pq: relation "signers" does not exist"`

That is due to Horizon wants to get information from Core, as Horizon is a plug-in above Core. But the table "signers" *does not exist at DB of Core yet*. (Likely your Core DB is still empty, without any schema)

Initialize the DB at Core and you will get a number of tables:

`stellar-core --newdb`

> After `--newdb` Core command, these tables are added / re-initialized at Core DB. (if successful)
>
> [image]
>
> (my Core is v9.2; v10 may vary a bit)

---

Also remember to initialize the history archive:

`stellar-core --newhist <YOUR-HIST-NAME>`

Comment: Thanks @cesarm. I found this out. Apparently my stellar core version was very old or --new db command was unable to create signers table. Getting latest version and setting up helped me to set the required tables properly.